# How to use MINUS operator in Impala/Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, impala

How can I use a MINUS operator query in Impala?

Example:

**Table:** Game

**Columns:** Official_start, halftime_start

I want to send a query in which halftime_start - official_start and save it as firsttimeplayed

I know that MINUS does not exist in Impala or HIVE but how can I do it without it?

Comment: Why do you say `col1 - col2` doesn't exits? Did you try it?  Are the datatypes of your columns correct?

Comment: When you say MINUS doesn't exist, what exactly you meant?  Try this in Hive or Impala...`select 10 - 5` and run the query

Comment: I saw another post on Stackoverflow in which someone said that MINUS did not exist in hive/impala. Thats why I was asking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MINUS` is a set-operation in some versions of SQL.  It operates on sets and in this way is similar to  `UNION` and `UNION ALL`.  It takes the *rows* from the first query that do not exist in the second.  I believe the ANSI standard for the operator is `EXCEPT` rather than `MINUS`.  Hive/Impala support neither `MINUS` nor `EXCEPT`.

`-` is the subtraction operator.  That appears to be what you want; it is the inverse operation of addition or `+`.  Unfortunately, another name for subtraction in English is "minus", leading to your confusion.

So, you just do:

```
select (halftime_start - official_start) as firsttimeplayed
. . .
```